# Star to delta transformation circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, delta, y-to-delta, star

Is it possible to use star-to-delta transformation on this specific circuit below? If it is possible, can someone give me a hint on how to do it?
I tried to do delta-to-star transformation and got the answer, but unsure with doing star-to-delta transformation on this circuit shown below. Please enlighten me on this. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below. I've transformed the 24 ohm, 120 ohm and 60 ohm into R1, R2 and R3 positions: -

[image]

If you do the math in value translation you can find current \$i_2\$ because: -

- R2 is in parallel with R4 and R3 is in parallel with R5
- they are then in series
- they are then in parallel with R1
- this means you can calculate the currents through 5 ohm and 43 ohms
- it follows that you can calculate the voltage on each node
- it then follows you can calculate \$i_2\$

I'll leave you to do the rest and don't forget, once you have \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$ you transform back to star to get the voltage across the 60 ohm.